# Run every N minutes or if item differs from average

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka.net

I have an actor which receives `WeatherConditions` and pushes it (by using `OfferAsync`) it to `source`. Currently it is setup to run for each item it receives (it stores it to db).

```
public class StoreConditionsActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public StoreConditionsActor(ITemperatureDataProvider temperatureDataProvider)
    {
        var materializer = Context.Materializer();
        var source = Source.Queue<WeatherConditions>(10, OverflowStrategy.DropTail);

        var graph = source
            .To(Sink.ForEach<WeatherConditions>(conditions => temperatureDataProvider.Store(conditions)))
            .Run(materializer);

        Receive<WeatherConditions>(i =>
        {
            graph.OfferAsync(i);
        });
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is:

1. Run it only once every N minutes and store average value of `WeatherConditions` from all items received in this N minutes time window
2. If item received matches certain condition (i.e. item temperature is 30% higher than previous item's temperature) run it despite of being "hidden" in time window.

I've been trying `ConflateWithSeed`, `Buffer`, `Throttle` but neither seems to be working (I'm newbie in Akka / Akka Streams so I may be missing something basic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer uses Akka Streams and Scala, but perhaps it will inspire your Akka.NET solution.

The `groupedWithin` method could meet your first requirement:

```scala
val queue =
  Source.queue[Int](10, OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
    .groupedWithin(10, 1 second)
    .map(group => group.sum / group.size)
    .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.left)
    .run()

Source(1 to 10000)
  .throttle(10, 1 second)
  .mapAsync(1)(queue.offer(_))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

In the above example, up to 10 integers per second are offered to the `SourceQueue`, which groups the incoming elements in one-second bundles and calculates the respective averages of each bundle.

As for your second requirement, you could use `sliding` to compare an element with the previous element. The below example passes an element downstream only if it is at least 30% greater than the previous element:

```scala
val source: Source[Int, _] = ???

source
  .sliding(2, 1)
  .collect {
    case Seq(a, b) if b >= 1.3 * a => b
  }
  .runForeach(println)
```

Comment: Nice solutions.  For the first requirement, I don't see why `SourceQueue` is needed though.  Why not just `throttle` + `grouped`?

Comment: Man, this `Akka` thing is powerfull :) Documentation (at least `.net` one) could be better though... Thanks!